# How to pass date parameter for a DB2 Table valued function

Tags: c#, sql, db2, user-defined-functions

I am new to DB2 and really hope one of you can help me. I am unable to create a Table valued function with parameter of type DATE.

I tried the following and I get the below exception:
[image]

The table valued function works fine with just the AddressCode.

I am using DBeaver to execute the script on AS400.

Code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS (STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE, ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9))
    RETURNS TABLE (ID INT, JOBNUMBER CHAR(9), CUSTOMERREFERENCE CHAR(18), 
    CONSIGNEENAME CHAR(30), CREATEDDATE DATE, AIRPORTOFORIGIN CHAR(3), AIRPORTOFARRIVAL CHAR(3),
    AIRPORTOFDESTINATION CHAR(3), COUNTRYOFDESTINATION CHAR(3), ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9), CONSIGNMENTNUMBER CHAR(25))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    RETURN
        SELECT  
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMJOBN DESC),  
                 A.EMJOBN,  
                 A.EMCREF,  
                 A.EMOSNM,
                 DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(A.EMCRTD), 'DDMMYY')),  
                 A.EMAOFO,  
                 A.EMAOFA,  
                 A.EMAOFD,  
                 A.EMCOFD,  
                 A.EMUKCD,
                 A.EMRPRT 
                 FROM DTALIBLE.EMASTER A WHERE A.EMPSFT = 'Y' AND A.EMUKCD = ADDRESSCODE AND 
                 DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(A.EMCRTD), 'DDMMYY')) >= STARTDATE AND DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(A.EMCRTD), 'DDMMYY')) <= ENDDATE
```

Comment: Is your Db2 database on i-series (as/400) ?  Please also state why you are using `alter function` instead of `create or replace function` which currently supported platforms allow.  Also state the Db2-column-datatype of the EMCRTD column.

Comment: @mao - Thanks for looking into this. You just gave me an idea and I tried the following. See my updated question. Cheers.

Comment: As per the answer below, when you use `alter function` it requires a different syntax.When you use `create function` or `create or replace function` you can name the parameters.  Your edited question is __different__ from your original question, so you should not ask two different questions in one thread. Additionally you should __confirm your Db2 platform and version__  (always do this when asking for help with Db2).

Comment: OK you created a new question and confirmed you are AS/400 though did not mention its version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using DB2 for I since the keyword CCSID is shown in the error popup

It's not the DATE keyword highlighted in your image that causes the problem, it's the DATE keyword in the parameters

you wrote

```
ALTER FUNCTION ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS (STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE, ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9))
RETURNS TABLE
```

you have to write

```
ALTER FUNCTION ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS
/* parameter type without name that indicate the signature */
(DATE, DATE, CHAR(9)) 

REPLACE RESTRICT
/*redefine parameters */
(STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE, ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9)) 
RETURNS TABLE ...
```